# Infinite product ??

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

can anyone help me in solving this question : 
I am searching for the different type of infinite product depending on a parameter (simple, absolute, uniform and normal convergence) : $\prod_{n>0}{u_n(x)}$ on an interval I, so what are the definition of each type ? Is there a relation between infinite product of function and series of function?
And how to study each type f convergence?
For example if we want to study on $]1;\infty[$  the product $\prod_{n>0}{\frac{nx+sin(x+sin(x))}{nx+e^x}}$ ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: $\prod_n (1+a_n)$ converges in $\mathbb{C}^*$  iff $\sum_n \log(1+a_n)$ converges in $\mathbb{C}/2i\pi \mathbb{Z}$. If $\sum_n |a_n|^2$ converges then it converges iff $\sum_n a_n$ converges

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that $\prod_{x_i\in X}x_i=\exp\left(\sum_{x_i\in X}\ln(x_i)\right)$ and $\sum_{x_i\in X}x_i=\ln\left(\prod_{x_i\in X}\exp(x_i)\right)$ because $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)\Rightarrow\exp(\ln(ab))=\exp(\ln(a)+\ln(b))\Rightarrow ab=\exp(\ln(a)+\ln(b))$ or because $ab=\exp(\ln(a))\exp(\ln(b))=\exp(\ln(a)+\ln(b))$. That is to say, if an infinite product is positive and convergent, then the infinite sum of its $ln$-ed components will be too. If the product is negative, consider making it positive by simply flipping the sign of the components. If you can't make the whole thing positive or negative, then it's likely that it wasn't convergent anyway, but that may depend on the problem.

In your example, one approach you may want to look into is sums of sums or products of products or some other such approach. This can help break a problem down into manageable components.

I've chosen to use base $e$ for my explanation, but any old base will do; and, depending on your problem, some bases will do better.